# two links that points to the same page simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I sort of ran into an issue I don't know how to solve and I would really appreciate any help at all regarding this. Okay, so I have my top navigation and whenever I click on this one particular link in the navigation called 'products that link leads to a page with a submenu with four other links below the top navigation. Now I am trying to make this link 'products' and also tnis link 'items' which is a submenu link to both go to same page once I click on the product links - the items page should show up with both products and the items link set to active. Both of these links should lead to one single page. Can someone please help me figure this out? I am just baffled here. I don't know what to do.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pyrot/N9bwB/1) - a very simple outline of the navigation.

HTML

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="items-page.html">products</a></li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav class="sub-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="items-page.html">itemes</a></li>
        <li>sub link 2</li>
        <li>sub link 3</li>
        <li>sub link 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
nav + nav {
    border-top: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

Comment: Can you add sample code? That is probably why this question was down voted.

Comment: What's the actual problem?  You tried to make two links target the same page. Do you get errors?  What happens when you click the links?

Comment: well both links go to the same page, but I have to click on them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit a jQuery like so:

```
//on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    //chnages path-two.html to path-one.html
    $('a[href="path-two.html"]').attr("href", "path-one.html");
    // if you are on the /path-one.html
    if(location.pathname == "/path-one.html") {
        // add active class
        $('a[href="path-one.html"]').addClass('active');
    };
});
```

with a bit of CSS something like this:

```
/*example active css, customize to your liking*/
.active {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9bwB/6/

If I am understanding your question right this should be what you need.

It's ugly as hell... I assume you are dealing with a CMS thats not to keen on customization?

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't work, nothing is happening. It's as if it isn't there.

Comment: I misunderstood for sure.
So I am guessing you are using a CMS and can't directly edit the <a> tags in question? And you are trying to change them on document ready with jQuery to both point to the same link and then on the products or items page you would like both links to show as active?

Comment: Here is a working fiddle that changes the second href: http://jsfiddle.net/N9bwB/4/

Comment: Okay, this fiddle has all the elements you need I think: http://jsfiddle.net/N9bwB/5/

Comment: ok, thank you very much this works with a site that uses css and html primarily, but I'm using laravel and for some reason it doesn't work with laravel, but I'm selecting this as the answer. Will definitely save it. Thanks again for all your assistance. I swear lavarel is such a pain. The active script that I have works but with holes in it. Hey quick question: can I copy and re-use an active script? I tried that but when I click on a main navigation link that has the same url as a submenu link only the submenu link takes the an active.

Comment: The active script works by checking the current location of the browser against the the value of the href attribute and adds the class of `.active` to it. I will only show the currently URL as active. If you want it to select more than one URL and just straight change their class do something like this.
`$('a[href="path-one.html"], a[href="path-two.html"]').addClass('active');` just comma separate your selectors :)